# Count occurrence of a list in a List of Lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list that looks something like this:

```
co_list = [[387, 875, 125, 822], [397, 994, 135, 941], [397, 994, 135, 941], [397, 994, 135, 941], [397, 994, 135, 941], [1766, 696, 1504, 643]. . . ]
```

I need to count the number of identical co-ordinates lists and return the count, 4 in this case.

So far I have tried:

```
def most_common(lst):
    lst = list(lst)
    return max(set(lst), key=lst.count)

for each in kk :
    print most_common(each)
```

Using which I get the most occurring element in each list. 
But my intention is to get a list if it's occurrence is more than 3.

Expected Output:

```
(element, count) = ([397, 994, 135, 941], 4)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I count the occurrences of a list item in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item-in-python)

Comment: @MoeA : I am glad that you are working great to remove duplicates , but this is different from what is asked in the link you posted ,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for that task:

```
from collections import Counter

co_list = [[387, 875, 125, 822], [397, 994, 135, 941], [397, 994, 135, 941], [397, 994, 135, 941], [397, 994, 135, 941], [1766, 696, 1504, 643]]

common_list, appearances = Counter([tuple(x) for x in co_list]).most_common(1)[0]  # Note 1
if appearances > 3:
    print((list(common_list), appearances))  # ([397, 994, 135, 941], 4)
else:
    print('No list appears more than 3 times!')
```

1) The inner `list`s are converted to `tuple`s because `Counter` builds a `dict` and `list`s being not hashable cannot be used as `key`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

def get_most_common_x_list(origin_list, x):

    counter = Counter(tuple(item) for item in origin_list)

    for item, count in most_common_list = counter.most_common():

        if count > x:

            yield list(item), count

        else:

            break
```